# Coordinates of world continents

Tags: php, geolocation

I am building a script that's powered by google maps where user chooses the a location from a map and save the long, lat in database aa a part of directory listing form.

I was thinking to add a search functionality by world continent for (America, Asia, Europe, Africa).

but this require having the coordinates of these locations like ***America long between 'xx' and 'yy', lat between 'aa' and 'bb'* so I can look it up in the database.***

And I don't seem to find these info any where,

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you describe the search functionality a bit more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, as a quick solution for this search functionality, I'd set-up two tables in a database. One would map every listing to a country, another would map every country to a continent, so that search could be performed joining these two tables. Use [google geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to get country from latitude/longitude if needed.

A mysql continent/country database can be found [here](http://drupal.org/node/161792).

Answer (score 3):

This website will help you quickly get your own bounding boxes:

http://bboxfinder.com

For example, for one project I didn't want to include Europe all the way North to [Knivskjellodden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knivskjellodden) or east to the Urals, so I drew this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are no simple "lat/lng bounding boxes" for the continents because the continents have [irregular boundaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borders_of_the_continents). For example Ankara in Turkey has approximatively lat=40, lng=33. But the latitude 40 crosses Europe, Asia and America; and the longitude 33 crosses Europe, Asia and Africa.

Similarly, there are no simple "lat/lng bounding boxes" for states.

Comment: basically what I'm trying to achieve is a map similar to one in [this website](http://www.worldeventsdiary.com/) where you can click on continent and it will look it up in the database. as per google map's recommendation I'm using float(10,6) for the long/lat fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the tiling algorithm of google maps you can try the spatial index to get all geo codes from a bounding box from a continent. Like the tiling algorithm this method is not very accurate.